# Unable to setPrice, setTaxClassId and setWeight when programmatically creating product

Tags: magento

I'm using Magento Community Edition ver. 1.6.2.0.

I’m trying to add a Simple product using the Varien Data Collection model (not the Api).

The product is being created, but the price, tax class id and weight are not being set.

I would be grateful if someone could advise as to why these particular product attributes are not being set.

Here’s my code:

```
// instatiate Product
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

    $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
    $product->setSku('99996');
    $product->setPrice(99.0000);
    $product->setAttributeSetId(4); 
    $product->setCategoryIds(array(2));
    $product->setType('Simple Product');
    $product->setName('Product Name6');
    $product->setDescription('The Product Description');
    $product->setShortDescription('Brief Description');
    $product->setStatus(1);    
    $product->setTaxClassId(2);
    $product->setWeight(1.0000);                
    $product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'));

    $product->save();

    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
    $stockItem->loadByProduct($product->getId());    
    if (! $stockItem->getId()) {
        $stockItem->setProductId($product->getId())->setStockId(1);
    }
    $stockItem->setData('inventory_manage_stock_default', 1);
    $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
    $stockItem->setData('qty', 10000);

    $stockItem->save();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Kind regards,

James

Comment: make sure that you havent disabled any tax modules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

---

Bug in

```
$product->setType('Simple Product');
```

replace with

```
$product->setTypeId('simple');
```

now price isset.
Because price in magento depends from product type.

Comment: Thanks Sergy, that solution was spot on!

Comment: You saved my life (y) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do not use:

```
$product->setType('Simple Product');
```

it does not set the product actually...it has been not working for a while...
as said above use:

```
  $product->setTypeId('simple')
```

This will actually set the type...as 'simple' has been defined in as a constant in mage/catalog...but not 'Simple Product'...

Answer (score 0):

As above said setting up `$product->setType('Simple');` would solve your problem. As it just did mine.